# What does this shell script mean?

Tags: linux, ntp, shell-scripting

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/sbin/ntpdate ntp.jst.mfeed.ad.jp
```

I found such a script file,maybe it is used to confirm the time, can you explain it in detail?

Comment: `man ntpdate` will explain it to you.

Answer (score 2):

`ntpdate` utility connects to the NTP server ntp.jst.mfeed.ad.jp, get the current time and set the local time closely to it.

It's like you correct the time on your watches according to the radio signal.

Answer (score 1):

It will set the time using `ntp.jst.mfeed.ad.jp` as source NTP server.

```
man ntpdate
```